# MapView doesn't work anymore if I add a GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, gestures

I'm trying to add a Pin at my map when the user does a longPress (with UILongPressGestureRecognizer), but this doesn't work. However, the bigger problem is: The map isn't displayed anymore. Why the map has disappeared?

You find the project-file [here](http://www.bansemer.net/dl/test1.zip)

---------------------------ViewController.swift--------------------------------

```
{

import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var theMapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet var theTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func theButton(sender: UIButton) {
    theLabel.text = "Swift-App schreibt \(theTextfield.text)"
    theTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Position
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 48.399193
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = 9.993341
    // Zoomfaktor
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    // 
    var theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta,longDelta)



    // Koordinaten der Kirche
    var churchLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    // Zentrum und Kartenausschnitt
    var theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(churchLocation, theSpan)


    // LongTap definieren
    let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: theMapView, action: "actionPin:")
    longpress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    longpress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    longpress.allowableMovement = 100
    theMapView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)


    // Karte anzeigen
    theMapView.setRegion(theRegion,animated:false)

    // Pin setzen
    var theUlmMinsterAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    theUlmMinsterAnnotation.coordinate = churchLocation
    theUlmMinsterAnnotation.title = "Ulmer Münster"
    theUlmMinsterAnnotation.subtitle = " Untertitel"

    theMapView.addAnnotation(theUlmMinsterAnnotation)
}

func actionPin(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    var touchpoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.theMapView)
    var newCoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D=theMapView.convertPoint(touchpoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.theMapView)
    var newAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    newAnnotation.coordinate = newCoord
    newAnnotation.title = "Fingertipp"
    newAnnotation.subtitle = "Untertitel"
    theMapView.addAnnotation(newAnnotation)
}

}}
```

Comment: If you could post the relevant code you might get a better response. What you are doing doesn't sound so complicated that it couldn't fit in a question.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard/xib to add `theMapView` to your view controller?

Comment: yes, i used the storyboard. The problem to display the map is solved with the hint from TonyMkenu (constrain wasnt defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your map size it's {0,0} and you are not using any constrain.

Check here the project with a minor update https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/test1-v2.zip

Comment: Thank you, now i see the map. constraints seems to be a important topic to learn something about. :)  But did you have any idea why the long-tap isnt recognized?

Comment: It's not so simple to add a long-tap on a MKMapView because there are others UIGestureRecognizer already... one solution can be.. subclassing MKMapView http://stackoverflow.com/a/21124351/1702413 ... or trying to "detect" these existing Gestures and requireGestureRecognizerToFail to all